# Error: near "end": (vcom-1576) expecting == or '+' or '-' or '&'

Tags: digital-logic, simulation, vhdl

It may be a simple fix, but I do not understand the error:

> Error: near "end": (vcom-1576) expecting == or '+' or '-' or '&'

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_STD.all;

entity SetPoint is
    Port (  
          SP_mm             : in    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
          SP_scalingFactor  : in    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
          RST               : in    STD_LOGIC;
          SP_error          : out   STD_LOGIC;
          SP_encoderUnits   : out   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0)
); 
            
end SetPoint;

architecture yours of SetPoint is
begin  

process(SP_mm, SP_scalingFactor, RST) 

begin
if (RST = '0' AND unsigned(SP_mm) > 1000) then
SP_error <= '1';
else
'0'
end if;

SP_encoderUnits <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(Shift_left("000000"&unsigned(SP_mm),to_integer(unsigned(SP_ScalingFactor))));

 

end process; 
end architecture yours;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce the exact error message you got (perhaps due to using a different simulator), but the error I got pointed towards the code:

```
else
'0'
end if;
```

It is strange to see `'0'` alone on a line like that.  It should have a semicolon at the end, and you likely meant it to be an assignment like:

```
SP_error <= '0';
```

You should also add some reasonable indentation to make your code easier to understand:

```
begin
    if (RST = '0' AND unsigned(SP_mm) > 1000) then
        SP_error <= '1';
    else
        SP_error <= '0';
    end if;
```

This compiles without errors on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/bJjn).